# How to upload image from img tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to upload photo to server form img tag, but i can't do it. plz help.
First I take photo from webcam, then i want to upload on my web server. When I Snap photo from webcam, it show on the screen by javascript method getelementbyId. Now I want to code that it will be uploaded to my web server.
Plz Help Thanks in advance.....
My Code is below:

```js
//script_photo.js

var photoButton = document.getElementById('snapPicture');
photoButton.addEventListener('click', picCapture, false);

navigator.getUserMedia ||
     (navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
          navigator.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:false}, onSuccess, onError);
     } else{
          alert('Your browser isnt supported');
}

function onSuccess(stream) {
     vidContainer = document.getElementById('webcam');
     var vidStream;
     if (window.webkitURL){
          vidStream = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
          }else{
               vidStream = stream;
     }
     vidContainer.autoplay = true;
     vidContainer.src = vidStream;

}

function onError(){
     alert('Houston, we have a problem');
}

function picCapture(){
     var picture = document.getElementById('capture'),
          context = picture.getContext('2d');

     picture.width = "600";
     picture.height = "400";
     context.drawImage(vidContainer, 0, 0, picture.width, picture.height);

     var dataURL = picture.toDataURL();
     document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
     <head>
          <title>My Photo Booth</title>
     <head>
     <body>
          <center>
          <video id="webcam" width="200" height="200"></video>
          <br>
          <input type="button" id="snapPicture" value="Snap A Picture!" />
          <p> 
          <canvas id="capture" style="display:none;"></canvas>
          <img id="canvasImg" alt="right click to save">
          <script src = "script_photo.js"></script>
          </center>          
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

`<img>` is an `html` element. The `data URI` that you created at created at `var dataURL = picture.toDataURL();`  is an image file.

You can `POST` the `data URI` that you created to server using `XMLHttpRequest()`, `FormData()`.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/path/to/server", true);
var data = new FormData();
data.append("image", dataURL, "imagename");
request.send(data);
```

Comment: @IrfanGondal See [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)